# Qt: how to update a frontend GUI with a backend thread?

Tags: qt, qt5, qthread, qt6

In Qt, how to update a frontend GUI with a backend thread?

This question may have been asked several times, but, couldn't find a *top-down* answer and *simple-working* example... Ending with nothing that works, and, misleading Qt docs all over the places that tells everything and it's opposite (override `QThread::run` in old days, don't do that but use "Workers" with `movetoThread` [use workers](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), and now "prefer run, avoid workers"?! [do not use workers](https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong)). At the end of the day, basic need, headache without solution...

With this `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
>> cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(dummyGUI LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)
add_executable(dummyGUI "main.cpp" "QDummyGUI.hpp" "QDummyWorker.hpp")
target_include_directories(dummyGUI PUBLIC Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(dummyGUI PUBLIC Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)
```

I create a Qt application:

```
>> cat main.cpp 
#include <QApplication>

#include "QDummyGUI.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QDummyGUI gui;
  gui.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

With a basic GUI which has just a counter to display:

```
>> cat QDummyGUI.hpp 
#pragma once
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QThread>
#include "QDummyWorker.hpp"
#include <sstream>

class QDummyGUI : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    QDummyGUI(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent) {
      // Build GUI.
      counter_ = new QLabel("0", this);
      auto * rootLayout_ = new QVBoxLayout();
      rootLayout_->addWidget(counter_);
      auto * window = new QWidget(this);
      window->setLayout(rootLayout_);
      setCentralWidget(window);
      // Runs task in backend with thread + worker.
      backendWorker_ = new QDummyWorker(); // do NOT set parent here.
      backendWorker_->moveToThread(&backendThread_);
      QObject::connect(&backendThread_, &QThread::started,
                       backendWorker_, &QDummyWorker::started);
      QObject::connect(&backendThread_, &QThread::finished,
                       backendWorker_, &QDummyWorker::finished);
      QObject::connect(backendWorker_, &QDummyWorker::sendData,
                       this, &QDummyGUI::recvData);
      backendThread_.start(); // Thread = worker parent HERE only.
    };
    ~QDummyGUI() {
      backendThread_.quit(); // Stop thread (send stop signal).
      backendThread_.wait(); // Wait for thread to be stopped.
    }

  public slots:
    void recvData(unsigned int const & count) {
      std::stringstream str; str << count;
      counter_->setText(str.str().c_str());
    };

  private:
    QLabel * counter_;
    QThread backendThread_; // Runs in GUI backend
    QDummyWorker * backendWorker_; // Handled by thread.
};
```

I need the counter to be updated (incremented) by a thread which must run in backend (the thread watch over backend stuffs, do some job, produce a result, and send that result back to the frontend GUI):

```
>> cat QDummyWorker.hpp 
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class QDummyWorker : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    QDummyWorker() {
      run_ = true;
    };

  public slots:
    void started() {
      std::cout << "QDummyWorker::started" << std::endl;
      unsigned int count = 0;
      while (run_) {
        // Need to constantly watch over stuffs and do some tasks accordingly.
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); // Doing stuffs takes some time.
        count++; // Doing stuffs produce a result.
        emit sendData(count); // Now need to update GUI with result produced in backend.
      };
    };
    void finished() {
      std::cout << "QDummyWorker::finished" << std::endl;
      run_ = false;
    };

  signals:
    void sendData(unsigned int const & count); // Qt MOC will provide this implementation.

  private:
    bool run_;
};
```

Note: replacing `finished` signals/slots by `quit` doesn't help.

Finally ending with a GUI displaying an updated counter (incremented every second) but can't stop the thread (closing GUI doesn't stop the thread - need to finish it with Ctrl-C)

```
>> ./dummyGUI
QDummyWorker::started
^C
```

Questions:

- What is the proper way to stop the thread when the GUI is closed (proper way to handle thread lifecycle)?
- Is this the "good" way to go? What would be the recommended solution in this situation according to *current* Qt best practices (seems they evolved...)?
- The "thread job" is actually an image conversion (which can take some time), and, the "counter" `count` is actually an image (so it's potentially a *big* data to transfer from backend thread to frontend GUI - large memory footprint): is there a way to make data (= `count` in this dummy example) copies will *not* occur when calling `sendData`  and `recvData`?

Comment: Since you don't run an event loop in the second thread, the signal/slot handling can't be done. Don't use a busy loop but call the event loop / let it call and work with e.g. a QTimer.

Comment: If it's only a matter of image conversion why don't you consider doing it using QtConcurrent::run method? You can find it here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html

Comment: Not sure to get what you mean. Can you modify the example to illustrate?
If I get what you mean: can't use QTimer, need to fetch images as fast as possible, can't rely on a timer with fixed frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution found:

```
>> cat QDummyGUI.hpp 
#pragma once
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QThread>
#include "QDummyWorker.hpp"
#include <sstream>

class QDummyGUI : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    QDummyGUI(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent) {
      // Build GUI.
      counter_ = new QLabel("0", this);
      auto * rootLayout_ = new QVBoxLayout();
      rootLayout_->addWidget(counter_);
      auto * window = new QWidget(this);
      window->setLayout(rootLayout_);
      setCentralWidget(window);
      // Runs task in backend with thread + worker.
      backendWorker_ = new QDummyWorker(); // do NOT set parent here.
      backendWorker_->moveToThread(&backendThread_);
      QObject::connect(&backendThread_, &QThread::started,
                       backendWorker_, &QDummyWorker::started);
      QObject::connect(&backendThread_, &QThread::finished,
                       backendWorker_, &QObject::deleteLater);
      QObject::connect(backendWorker_, &QDummyWorker::sendData,
                       this, &QDummyGUI::recvData);
      backendThread_.start(); // Thread = worker parent HERE only.
    };
    ~QDummyGUI() {
      backendThread_.requestInterruption(); // Stop Worker.
      backendThread_.quit(); // Stop thread (send stop signal).
      backendThread_.wait(); // Wait for thread to be stopped.
    }

  public slots:
    void recvData(unsigned int const & count) {
      std::stringstream str; str << count;
      counter_->setText(str.str().c_str());
    };

  private:
    QLabel * counter_;
    QThread backendThread_; // Runs in GUI backend
    QDummyWorker * backendWorker_; // Handled by thread.
};
```

```
>> cat QDummyWorker.hpp 
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class QDummyWorker : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    QDummyWorker() {
      std::cout << "QDummyWorker::created" << std::endl;
    };
    ~QDummyWorker() {
      std::cout << "QDummyWorker::destroyed" << std::endl;
    };

  public slots:
    void started() {
      std::cout << "QDummyWorker::started" << std::endl;
      unsigned int count = 0;
      while (!QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested()) {
        // Need to constantly watch over stuffs and do some tasks accordingly.
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); // Doing stuffs takes some time.
        count++; // Doing stuffs produce a result.
        emit sendData(count); // Now need to update GUI with result produced in backend.
      };
    };

  signals:
    void sendData(unsigned int const & count); // Qt MOC will provide this implementation.
};
```